# cx-oracle sql insert query raise error when : (semicolon) insert into query

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, sql-insert, cx-oracle

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('myip', '1521', service_name='myservicename')
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='passwd', dsn=dsn_tns) 
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  tablename VALUES (7.4)")
    #above works ok
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  tablename VALUES (7:4)")
    #above sql raise cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00917: missing comma
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

My requirement to is to insert **:** to be insert in this tablename, column type of this tablename is varchar2. ( when i insert '0001' it also remove leading zeros and only insert '1' in tabename)
above code connect oracle database table and create cursor to execute sql insert query. in insert query with values 7.4 if successfully update the table but in second insert it raise error with ORA-00917.
i am using oracle version 11g and python 3.7.

Comment: then `tablename` should be a table with only one column of numeric type, for this reason `7:4` will not make sense.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for reply but it seems something other issue because table column is of varchar2 type and beside : (semicolon) it also unable to insert leading zeros.

Comment: you're welcome. If the data type is varchar, then you should quote it `'7:4'`, `7.4` is implicitly considered as a numeric value which would not meet a problem during the insertion of a varchar type column, but the reverse case ( char to numeric ) may not suceed mostly

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you are right and it works with '7:4',  but raise when i use variable, cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00936: missing expression                                    myvar='7:4'
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO  tablename(col1) VALUES ({myvar})')

Comment: Now, there are single quotes within single quotes that would raise error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, the value in first case can be classified into a type which is numeric which might be inserted into a string type column. Converting that into a prepared statement such as

```
myvar=7.4
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES (:1)",[myvar])
```

that cannot be used for `7:4` which doesn't seem to be converted to a known data type even implicitly. The value should be quoted `7:4`, and would be suitable to be formatted  for this case such as

```
myvar='7:4'
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tab(col) VALUES (:1)",[myvar.format('{}')])
```

As a result, prefer using this second one for both cases without having a problem.